# .htaccess RewriteCond syntax

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to expose an internal folder to the root url of my site.
So I need to redirect users to `/public/`
BUT it should NOT redirect if you visit site.com

I've tried this but can't get it to work:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

**edit:**
for example it should return `/public/some-image.jpg`
when you visit `site.com/some-image.jpg`
otherwise just execute `/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^public
RewriteCond $1 !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What does $1 contain when there is no RewriteRule prior to it to capture anything in the $1 backreference?

Comment: doesn't fix my problem, I've edited the question to clarify it, thanks

Comment: @Ansari It seems backwards but mod_rewrite first tries to match the regular expression to the url, then it runs all the rewritecond condition, and then is will generate the url as specified by the second argument of RewriteRule. So in this case $1 will contain the match of the RewriteRule that is after it. Pretty weird when I first saw it, but it's very powerful.

Comment: RewriteCond $1 !^$ I've tried that already, it returns 404 (if you visit the root)